# Setting Google Services to Restrict Background Data blocks Firebase Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-settings

After testing thoroughly with a client, we found that when this setting is enabled and the user is using **mobile data connection**, we do not receive **Firebase cloud messages**. We tested with other apps like Whatsapp and they worked fine so that rules out problems with network provider, data and connection.

The setting can be found by going to Settings -> Sounds and notifications -> App notifications -> **Google Services**.

On my phone android 5.1.1 Google Services does not exist, only Google Play Services which does not have the same effect when enabling **Restrict Background Data**.

The user's phone that has this problem is Samsung S5 (model SM-G900F),  Android 5.0.

When checking the Firebase logs and diagnosing with this users Firebase token, we were able to see that Firebase determined that the device was disconnected when this setting is enabled using only mobile data connection - when wifi is used then there is no problem.

How would I check this setting in our app? A similar question was asked here [Warn user if Google Services' Restrict background data option is activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020733/warn-user-if-google-services-restrict-background-data-option-is-activated) with no responses. Running a search gave me one possible way to check it for our app, but we want to check it for "Google Services" (NOT our app and NOT "Google Play Services"). The implementation looks like this:

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean bgData = mgr.getBackgroundDataSetting();
```

First prize will be to actually change the setting programatically, but even if we are only able to detect the setting, we will be happy. From endless searching I can tell there won't be a simple answer to this.